# View Controller transition for app using facebook (xcode) (swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift

I'm an having trouble with the transition from my facebook login page to my home view controller. It works fine when you sign in to facebook for the first time but once you re-open the app after you have signed in things start to get hairy. What I want is for the app to recognize that the user has already logged in so that it can skip the facebook login page and transition into my home view controller without ever bringing up the login page. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think what you want to do is have a 'remember me' kind of feature?

1. In order to do this, you'd want to save the user data somewhere when the user first signs in.

eg.
    `.writeToFile(...)`

2. Then, you'd want to test to see if that file exists each time the user logs in, extract the username/password, and then login.

eg. `loginD = String(contentsOfFile: ...)`

3. Once this action occurs, you can trigger a custom view segue, by which you create a link between the login button and the home button, give it an identifier, and then trigger it from the view controller.

eg. `.performSegueWithIdentifier(...)`

Hope this helps!